# Different r.v. under the Binomial dist.

Tags: probability, statistics

Supposing $W_1,W_2,...,W_m$ is an iid and has dist Binomial with parameters $(t,p)$.

What is the $p(t^*\neq t)$ with estimator $t^*=\max_{i=1,...,m} W_i$?

What I did: found it is equivalent in idea to $p(t^*\le k)$. I get a product of sums mess. How can I sort this?

Answer should look like $(1-p^t)^m$

Comment: You should use $W^*$ instead of $w^*$ to emphasise that $W^*$ is a random variable. Expanding on this point, is $w$ a fixed constant or random?

Comment: Whoops! See edits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:
$$P(t^* \ne t) = P(t^* \le t-1) = P(W_1 \le t-1) \cdot P(W_2 \le t-1) \cdots P(W_m \le t-1).$$

Comment: This is where I said I was stuck: $\prod_1^m P(W_i\leq t-1)$. The inner prob is the CDF of Bin so I get a sum and that's where I get lost.

Comment: @Lock $P(W_i \le t-1) = 1 - P(W_i = t)$.

Comment: Oh!! I got it. A nice Bin pdf that cancels out nicely! Thanks!